# Как в скобки массива вставить переменную?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив { "user": "здесь должна быть переменная" }, но вот в чём проблема. Я хочу вставить внутрь переменную, но когда я делаю так: { "user": "} {" } он считает что } { это текст, поэтому я не могу вставить переменную.

Comment: а почему сразу переменную не использовать: `{"user": variable }`?

Comment: @Grundy разве так можно?

Comment: а почему нет? :)

Comment: @Grundy я мб тупой, но у меня не работает https://jsfiddle.net/yasfq5o3/1/

Comment: если ты откроешь консоль браузера, ты увидишь почему именно и что конкретно не работает

Comment: @Grundy ну да, я понял. Напиши ответ, я помечу как правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, у вас есть объект. У каждого свойства есть ключ (также называемый «имя» или «идентификатор»), который НЕ обязательно писать в кавычках.
Например...

```
let user = {     // объект
  name: "John",  // под ключом "name" хранится значение "John"
  age: 30        // под ключом "age" хранится значение 30
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yasfq5o3/1/

Здесь у вас проблема... "abc" это строка, должна быть в кавычках.
(`var test = "abc";`)

И если вы только начали программировать JS, то совет: не использовать var, в место этого используйте let(иногда const).

Для дополнительной информации оставляю link: https://learn.javascript.ru/object

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что abc должна была быть строкой?

Comment: Консоль выдаёт ощибку, что abc  не найден,(reference error: variable not defined), вы должны были либо определить переменное(например const abc = "что-то"; var test = abc;), либо "abc "должна быть строкой.

Comment: _либо "abc "должна быть строкой_ - почему опять строкой?

Comment: ну если вы определите его, то может быть любого типа, например let abc = 3;, но если не определить, будет ошибка. А если просто написать abc, всё что можете, это написать в кавычках.